# Legal ways to get all recent posts of multiple Facebook pages as soon as possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to get all the newest posts from 10 (or let's say 1xxxxx) Facebook pages (which I do not own) as soon as they there published without manual refreshing all 10 pages every second. What legal tools should I use?

Comment: why would you want to do that for pages you don´t own? you are not allowed to use the content anywhere anyway, because...well, it´s not your content ;) - also, scraping is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the Facebook Graph API. It allows you to get your application notified via callback HTTP posts whenever certain updates occur.  You'll find the API documentation for this feature here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2

Based on your usage, you may have to pay for that service.

Comment: Thanks! But does this API shows me all updates of preferred Facebook pages without they owners let's (enables) me to get them?

Comment: Humm... the Facebook doc suggest it will work for your app users and pages that have installed your app.  You may want to contact Facebook if they offer more generic real-time updates.  If that does not work for you, you may have to periodically pull instead, specifying a start date every time (matching the last time you did the pull).  The Graph API should still be used for this over scraping Facebook pages.  Doing it constantly for over 100K pages as you suggest is quite aggressive though.  You may have to contact them for special access as you will likely reach their query quotas.